# How to set default arguments for Handlebars templates?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I've written a template helper that inserts a link, fairly straightforward.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('link_to', function(href, title) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString('<a href="/' + href + '">' + title + '</a>');
});
```

And its usage is like so:

```
{{ link_to 'articles' 'Articles' }}
```

However, it seems a bit redundant for me to specify a capitalised version in the second parameter if the href is self-describing. So I'd like to set this behaviour automatically if the title parameter is omitted. Something like the following:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('link_to', function(href, title) {
    if (!title) {
        title = href.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + href.slice(1);
    }
    return new Handlebars.SafeString('<a href="/' + href + '">' + title + '</a>');
});
```

However, when rendered with `{{ link_to 'articles' }}` I just get `[object Object]`. It's not a big deal to keep the second parameter, but I was just wondering if there was a way around this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Helpers accept an optional Hash as its final argument.If the template provides no hash arguments, Handlebars will automatically pass an empty object ({}).

[From https://handlebars-lang.github.io/docs/guide/block-helpers.html#hash-arguments ]

So, when you are having title in the helpers parameter list it is treated as the Hash object. You can check that by logging title in console. So for your code to work you can just check that if the type of title is String or not using the typeof operator.

```
if(!title || typeof title != 'String') {
    title = href.toString().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + href.slice(1);
}
```

and it should work. Working example :
http://jsfiddle.net/prabhat_rai/ve4h39vm/

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to use the hash arguments in handlebars seems to be to check for the expected optional parameters in the `hash` attribute of the `options` argument (passed to any helper as last argument).

In the OP example this would look like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('link_to', function(href) {
    var options = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    var title = options.hash.title || href.toString().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + href.slice(1);
    return new Handlebars.SafeString('<a href="/' + href + '">' + title + '</a>');
});
```

This way the helper can be used like this

```
{{ link_to 'articles' title='Articles' }}
```

or this

```
{{ link_to 'articles' }}
```

This has the advantage that you can add any number of optional template arguments and not just one. That is the above example could easily extended to provide an optional tooltip as well:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('link_to', function(href) {
    var options = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    var title = options.hash.title || href.toString().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + href.slice(1);
    var tooltip = options.hash.tooltip || title;
    return new Handlebars.SafeString('<a href="/' + href + '" title="' + tooltip + '">' + title + '</a>');
});
```

Now both `title` and `tooltip` can be specified independent of each other. I.e. you can specify a tooltip but no custom title:

```
{{ link_to 'articles' tooltip='Go to Articles' }}
```

Comment: Not sure this will work, when the second param is passed (as a string) the call to `options.hash.title` will fail with `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`.

Comment: @doublejosh all optional arguments need to be passed in the way `<arg>=<value>` otherwise handlebars will shift the `options` argument to the right and break the helper.

Comment: Sure. I'm referring to how to you inspect the options param within the helper. Since `options` can be a string when a second param is present, then referencing that nested property causes an error.

Comment: @doublejosh to cope for an arbitrary number of arguments you could use the `arguments` object inside the helper function. The options object will always be `arguments[arguments.length - 1]`. I adapted my answer accordingly.

Comment: That's wonderful information!!! This portion of Handlebars is undocumented.

Answer (score 2):

fix your helpers.  The options object makes this difficult.  So by wrapping the functions with something that moves around the arguments you have more reasonable code assuming you will have multiple helpers with optional arguments

```
function fixHelper(func) {
  return function(){
    var aArgs=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)
      ,opts=aArgs.pop();
    aArgs.unshift(opts);
    return func.apply(this, aArgs);
  }

 function link_to(options, href, title) {
    title = title || href.ucfirst()
    return new Handlebars.SafeString('<a href="/' + href + '">' + title + '</a>')
 }
 Handlebars.registerHelper('link_to', fixHelper(link_to))
```